# Export multiple tables from Access DB to Excel workbook with formatting and layout

Tags: excel, database, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to export multiple tables using VBA script given below, it successfully exports all the table data in a workbook with multiple worksheets but the data formatting and layouts is not preserved as when you do it manually by selecting single table and checking to preserve data formatting and layout.

Is there anyway to use vba script to export all the tables with formatting and layout?

```
Sub expotT()
    Dim td As DAO.TableDef, db As DAO.Database
    Set db = CurrentDb()
    For Each td In db.TableDefs
        If Left(td.Name, 4) <> "msys" Then
            DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
                                      td.Name, "C:\xExcelTables.xls", True, td.Name
        End If 
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you need to export ALL tables from a relational database to flat file spreadsheet? If for migration to other systems, there are other ways. Remember [Excel is not a database](https://www.google.com/search?q=excel+is+not+a+database).

Comment: I need it for migration, will be performing import from posgresql. Is there any other way of doing this. I need postgresql working as backend db and access to still work as front-end (No data should be there).

Comment: Then connect Postgres directly to MS Access using [linked tables](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/import-or-link-to-data-in-another-access-database-095ab408-89c7-45b3-aac2-58036e45fcf6) and run insert/select queries for migration. MS Access is designed to connect to *any* compliant ODBC/OLEDB backend (not just SQL Server). Read the many docs, tutorials, articles out there!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By *manually* exporting Access tables means using the GUI ribbon feature `External Data > Export > Excel`, then the corresponding method would be [DoCmd.OutputTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.outputto) and not [DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.transferspreadsheet) where the latter is the faster Excel exporter without any formatting. However, the former does not allow the easy facility of adding worksheets but only exports each table to whole workbooks.

Consequently, you need to interface to the `Excel.Application` COM object to migrate all exported workbooks to a single final workbook with original formatting. You can do so with VBA with Excel's [`Worksheet.Copy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.copy) method.

```
Public Sub ExportAccTables()
    Dim td As DAO.TableDef, db As DAO.Database
    Dim xlApp As Object, targetWb As Object, sourceWb As Object
    Dim strFile As String

    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set targetWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add()                  ' CREATE NEW WORKBOOK

    Set db = CurrentDb()

    For Each td In db.TableDefs
        If Left(td.name, 4) <> "msys" Then
            ' EXPORT INDIVIDUAL WORKBOOKS
            strFile = "C:\Path\To\Excel_" & td.name & ".xls"
            DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputTable, td.name, acFormatXLS, strFile

            ' COPY FORMATTED WORKSHEET TO TARGET WORKBOOK
            Set sourceWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strFile)
            sourceWb.Worksheets(1).Copy After:=targetWb.sheets(targetWb.sheets.Count)
            sourceWb.Close False

            ' DELETE INDIVIDUAL WORKBOOK
            If Len(Dir(strFile)) <> 0 Then Kill strFile
        End If
    Next td

    targetWb.sheets(1).Delete                            ' DELETE DEFAULT FIRST SHEET
    targetWb.SaveAs "C:\Path\To\FinalWorkbook.xls", 56   ' SAVE TARGET WORKBOOK (.xls)
    targetWb.Close True                                  ' CLOSE WORKBOOK
    xlApp.Quit                                           ' QUIT BACKGROUND APP

    ' RELEASE RESOURCEES
    Set td = Nothing: Set db = Nothing
    Set sourceWb = Nothing: Set targetWb = Nothing: Set xlApp = Nothing
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please explain why 56 is there in this line: targetWb.SaveAs "C:\Path\To\FinalWorkbook.xls", 56

Comment: Hi Parfait, I tried running your script but there is an error stating -> "Run-time error: 2306 There are too many rows to output based on the limitations specified by the output format or MS access".

Comment: Does any of your tables exceed Excel's 2*20 (or 1,048,576) row limit?

Comment: I don't think so. no.

Comment: The older `.xls` Excel has a maximum of 2^16 (or 65,536) row limit. Use `.xlsx` instead. So change extension and `acFormatXLSX` type.